# how to handle Trying to get property of non-object error in laravel?

Tags: laravel

[image]I am deleting item from cart and after deleting i am displaying fresh result. but all item from cart table is delete i am getting this error

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\avitra\resources\views\ordersummary.blade.php)

for following query. When all item is removed from cart & it display then it can not get any record from cart table so it return null value and getting above error? How can i handle this error in laravel?

```
$getCartResult=DB::table('product_details')
                     ->join('cart','cart.product_id','=','product_details.product_id')
                     ->join('subcategory','product_details.sub_id','=','subcategory.sub_id')
                     ->select('subcategory.image','subcategory.name_of_subcategory','product_details.*','cart.*')
                     ->where('cart.user_id',$userid)
                     ->get();
```

blade file:

```
<?php $getCartResult=DB::table('product_details')
                     ->join('cart','cart.product_id','=','product_details.product_id')
                     ->join('subcategory','product_details.sub_id','=','subcategory.sub_id')
                     ->select('subcategory.image','subcategory.name_of_subcategory','product_details.*','cart.*')
                     ->where('cart.user_id',$userid)
                     ->get();
                 ?>
                 <?php
                if (!empty($getCartResult)) {
                 ?>
                 <div class="card-body cart_show" style="overflow-y: scroll;height: 300px;display:none;">
                    @foreach($getCartResult as $v_contents)
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
                            <div>
                                <img src="{{asset('images/'.$v_contents->image)}}" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <center>
                            <div class="input-group mt-2" style="width:100px">

                                  <button type="button" class="cart-btn btn-default btn-number cart_qtyminus"  data-type="minus" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
                                      <span class="fa fa-minus cart-fa"></span>
                                  </button>

                             <!--  <input type="text" name="cart_qty" class="form-control input-number" value="{{$v_contents->qty}}" min="1" max="10"> -->
                              <span class="cart_quantity " style="border: 1px solid;height: 30px;width:30px;"><?php echo $v_contents->qty; ?></span>

                                  <button type="button" class="cart-btn btn-default btn-number cart_qtyplus" data-type="plus" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>" data-value="<?php echo $v_contents->product_id;?>">
                                      <span class="fa fa-plus cart-fa"></span>
                                  </button>

                            </div>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-5 mt-3">
                            <div>
                                <span><b>{{$v_contents->name_of_subcategory}}</b></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mt-2">
                                <span>Seller : Avitra Ayurved</span>
                            </div>
                            <?php  $subtotal=$v_contents->discount_price*$v_contents->qty; ?>
                            <div class="mt-2">
                                Price :<span class="cart_subtotal"><?php echo $subtotal; ?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mt-2">
                                <span><a class="btn btn-sm mt-3 cart_delete" data-id="<?php echo $v_contents->cart_id;?>"><span style="color: #FBA842;"><b>REMOVE</b></span></a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="mt-2">
                                <span>Delivery by Fri Jan 24 | Free</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><hr>
                    @endforeach
                    <div>
                        <span style="float: right;"><button class="btn btn-sm continue cart_payment_show"><span><b>CONTINUE</b></span></button></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your query is not returning any result and your are trying to access it's property something like  `$getCartResult->id`.

To resolve this you can check if item exists or not using `if` condition on your blade template for e.g

```
@if(!empty($getCartResult))
 // your code
@endif
```

Comment: @AshutoshMali Can you please share ordersummary.blade.php file. Also the line no where you are getting this error

Comment: how can i share this file?

Comment: Also please share the screenshot of your error. You can upload image by editing your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208787/discussion-between-sehdev-and-ashutosh-mali).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to access a row that has been deleted. Check the query that you are returning after deleting an item.